# Can we use monoammonium phospate (MAP) as yeast nutrient for wine making?

Tags: wine, yeast-starters, yeast-cultures, yeast-nutrient

Wine making is not common in my country so it's difficult to buy wine ingredient especially Diammonium Phosphate (DAP) as yeast nutrient. After look in local shop, there's a shop selling Monoammonium Phosphate (MAP). Can we use it as yeast nutrient in wine making?
Is there any journal or research that claim MAP safe to use as yeast nutrient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monoammonium phosphate and diammonium phosphate contain all the same chemical compounds (phosphate ions, ammonium ions, and hydrogen ions), the major difference is that MAP has a second hydrogen in place of the ammonium.

So, if you buy food grade stuff, it should be totally safe to consume, however, pH is determined by those hydrogen ions, so your wine may end up being more acidic. I'm not sure on this last part (you could calculate it with the Ka of H2PO4 vs HPO4). If you don't have other options, it's worth a shot.

Comment: Will the acid be significantly increased by MAP? I am looking for a possibility that the acid problem is managed to be stabilized by calcium carbonate or potassium carbonate.

Comment: I'm not sure. The pka of dihydrogen phosphate is 7.2, which means that it shouldn't give off many hydrogen ions at neutral pH. In fact it might buffer the solution a bit. Do you have any pH strips? Your best bet would be to separate out some of your grape must, test the pH, add some MAP and test again.